# Correct way to get single (first) value from functions that returns a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

What is the Pythonic way to get a single (the first) value from a function that returns a tuple?

I have come up with two solutions that work

```
Byte=unpack_from('B',Inbuff,42)[0]
```

VS

```
Byte,=unpack_from('B',Inbuff,42)
```

Personally I prefer the first because it will not break if the return tuple has more than one value (Not going to happen here but possible in a more generic case)

Comment: I am using version 2.7. (Should have made that clear up front). Thanks sweeneyrod, your solution is very clear for version 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically want the first value (it seems that you do, but your question just said "a single value" rather than "the first value"), your first method is better. The second one is more like a Python party trick (and will, as sweeneyrod pointed out, will break if it receives a tuple longer than one element).

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x I would favour a third:

```
byte, *_ = unpack_from('B',Inbuff,42)
```

This stores the rest of the tuple in the variable `_`, which is the most commonly used value for a throwaway variable.

The second seems odd to me. It seems unlikely that the function would only ever return tuples with only one element. The first has the advantage that it is more readable to people who are unused to Python and features specific to it such as iterable unpacking.

For Python 2.x, I think that the first is better. "Readability counts", *and* it is more robust.

Comment: Note that the "rest of the tuple" is stored as a list, which means the `*_` will have to iterate through the whole tuple and throw most of it away. Using `[0]` avoids creating a useless list.